# How to make sure that readyRead() signals from QTcpSocket can't be missed?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket

When using `QTcpSocket` to receive data, the signal to use is `readyRead()`, which signals that new data is available. 
However, when you are in the corresponding slot implementation to read the data, no additional `readyRead()` will be emitted. 
This may make sense, as you are already in the function, where you are reading all the data that is available.

### Problem description

However assume the following implementation of this slot:

```
void readSocketData()
{
    datacounter += socket->readAll().length();
    qDebug() << datacounter;
}
```

What if some data arrives after calling `readAll()` but before leaving the slot? 
What if this was the last data packet sent by the other application (or at least the last one for some time)?
No additional signal will be emitted, so you have to make sure to read all the data yourself.

### One way to minimize the problem (but not avoid it totally)

Of course we can modify the slot like this:

```
void readSocketData()
{
    while(socket->bytesAvailable())
        datacounter += socket->readAll().length();
    qDebug() << datacounter;
}
```

However, we haven't solved the problem. It is still possible that data arrives just after the `socket->bytesAvailable()`-check (and even placing the/another check at the absolute end of the function doesn't solve this).

### Making sure to be able to reproduce the problem

As this problem of course happens very rarely, I stick to the first implementation of the slot, and I'll even add a an artificial timeout, to be sure that the problem occurs:

```
void readSocketData()
{
    datacounter += socket->readAll().length();
    qDebug() << datacounter;

    // wait, to make sure that some data arrived
    QEventLoop loop;
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();
}
```

I then let another application send 100,000 bytes of data. 
This is what happens:

> new connection!
>   32768 (or 16K or 48K)

The first part of the message is read, but the end isn't read anymore, as `readyRead()` won't be called again.

My question is: what is the best way to be sure, this problem never occurs?

### Possible solution

One solution I came up with is calling the same slot again at the end again, and to check at the beginning of the slot, if there is any more data to read:

```
void readSocketData(bool selfCall) // default parameter selfCall=false in .h
{
    if (selfCall && !socket->bytesAvailable())
        return;

    datacounter += socket->readAll().length();
    qDebug() << datacounter;

    QEventLoop loop;
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();

    QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(readSocketDataSelfCall()));
}

void readSocketDataSelfCall()
{
    readSocketData(true);
}
```

As I don't call the slot directly, but use `QTimer::singleShot()`, I assume that the `QTcpSocket` can't know that I'm calling the slot again, so the problem that `readyRead()` isn't emitted can't happen anymore.

The reason why I have included the parameter `bool selfCall` is that the slot which is called by the `QTcpSocket` isn't allowed to exit sooner, else the same problem can occur again, that data arrives exactly at the wrong moment and `readyRead()` isn't emitted.

Is this really the best solution to solve my problem? 
Is the existence of this problem a design error in Qt or am I missing something?

Comment: Very good question and very well described.

Comment: I think that when starting an event loop you permit Qt to process events, like for example reading from the network interface. If you don't do this (try sleep instead), this should not happen. Putting [`QCoreApplication::processEvents()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) between some smaller sleeps probably equals your scenario again, as Qt processes incoming data, sees that you're currently within a slot connected to readyRead(), so it will not call it again, and your checker is again missed.

Comment: But still: The question might be turned into "How to correctly handle this when I *might* permit Qt to process events?" (Remember that if you say "Ok then I just don't permit Qt to process events, and it's fixed", you might one day rewrite your slot and forget that you should not do so. Boom.)

Comment: Yes you are right. However I really had this problem some time ago (without any artificial delay). Unfortunately I'm not sure anymore how I managed to get into this problem in the first place, but it was probably due to different threads. With multithreading, this problem will still exist

Comment: I wish some Qt super programmer would answer this!  I'm having the same issue and I can't figure out how to solve this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Short answer

The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) of `QIODevice::readyRead()` states:

> `readyRead()` is not emitted recursively; if you reenter the event loop or call `waitForReadyRead()` inside a slot connected to the `readyRead()` signal, the signal will not be reemitted.

Thus, make sure that you

- **don't** instantiate a `QEventLoop` inside your slot,
- **don't** call `QApplication::processEvents()` inside your slot,
- **don't** call `QIODevice::waitForReadyRead()` inside your slot,
- **don't** use the same `QTcpSocket` instance within different threads.

Now you should always receive **all** data sent by the other side.

---

## Background

The `readyRead()` signal is emitted by [`QAbstractSocketPrivate::emitReadyRead()`](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/network/socket/qabstractsocket.cpp?h=5.12#n1300) as follows:

```
// Only emit readyRead() when not recursing.
if (!emittedReadyRead && channel == currentReadChannel) {
    QScopedValueRollback<bool> r(emittedReadyRead);
    emittedReadyRead = true;
    emit q->readyRead();
}
```

The `emittedReadyRead` variable is rolled back to `false` as soon as the `if` block goes out of scope (done by the `QScopedValueRollback`). So the only chance to miss a `readyRead()` signal is when the control flow reaches the `if` condition again **before** the processing of the last `readyRead()` signal has finished (in other words, when there would be a recursion).

And a recursion should only be possible in the situations listed above.

Comment: It' an brilliant answer. Can I instantiate the QEventLoop after a call to 'write' function,these are both  in a slot function that was connect to some signal other than  signal 'readReady()'

Answer (score 7):

I think scenario mentioned in this topic has two major cases which works differently, but in general QT doesn't have this problem at all and I will try to explain below why.

First case: Single threaded application.

Qt uses select() system call to poll open file descriptor for any change happened or operations available. Simple saying on every loop Qt checks if any of opened file descriptors have data available to read/closed etc. So on single threaded application flow looks like that (code part simplified)

```
int mainLoop(...) {
     select(...);
     foreach( descriptor which has new data available ) {
         find appropriate handler
         emit readyRead; 
     }
}

void slotReadyRead() {
     some code;
}
```

So what will happend if new data arrived while program still inside slotReadyRead.. honestly nothing special. OS will buffer data, and as soon as control will return to next execute of select() OS will notify software that there are data available for particular file handle. It works in absolutely the same way for TCP sockets/files etc.

I can imaging situations where (in case of really long delays in slotReadyRead and a lot of data coming) you can experience an overrun within OS FIFO buffers (for example for serial ports) but that has more to do with a bad software design rather then QT or OS problems.

You should look on slots like readyRead like on a interrupt handlers and keep their logic only within fetch functionality which fills your internals buffers while processing should be done in separate threads or while application on idle etc.. Reason is that any such application in general is a mass service system and if it spends more time on serving one request then a time interval between two requests it's queue will overrun anyway.

Second scenario: multithreaded application

Actually this scenario is not that much differ from 1) expect that you should design right what happens in each of your threads. If you keep main loop with light wighted 'pseudo interrupt handlers' you will be absolutely fine and keep processing logic in other threads, but this logic should work with your own prefetch buffers rather then with QIODevice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is quite interesting.

In my program the usage of QTcpSocket is very intensive. So I've written the whole library, that breaks outgoing data into packages with a header, data identifier, package index number and maximum size, and when the next piece of data comes, I know exactly where it belongs to. Even if I miss something, when the next `readyRead` comes, the receiver reads all and compose received data correctly. If the communication between your programs is not so intense, you could do the same, but with timer (which is not very fast, but solves the problem.)

About your solution. I don't think it's better then this:

```
void readSocketData()
{
    while(socket->bytesAvailable())
    {
        datacounter += socket->readAll().length();
        qDebug() << datacounter;

        QEventLoop loop;
        QTimer::singleShot(1000, &loop, SLOT(quit()));
        loop.exec();
    }
}
```

The problem of both methods is the code right after leaving the slot, but before returning from emitting the signal.

Also you could connect with `Qt::QueuedConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples of ways to get the whole file, but using some other parts of the QNetwork API:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-downloadmanager.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-download.html

These examples show a stronger way to handle the TCP data, and when buffers are full, and better error handling with a higher level api.

If you still want to use the lower level api, here is a post with a great way to handle the buffers:

Inside your `readSocketData()` do something like this:

```
if (bytesAvailable() < 256)
    return;
QByteArray data = read(256);
```

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/11494-QTcpSocket-readyRead-and-buffer-size

EDIT: Additional examples of how to interact with QTCPSockets:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-fortuneserver.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-fortuneclient.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-blockingfortuneclient.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, the example you provide uses `QNetworkAccessManager`, `QNetworkRequest` and `QNetworkReply`. Afaik these are however only thought to be used with HTTP methods, not any TCP protocol you want to. My example with transferring data from one device to another one was just an example, I want to be able to send arbitrary data over TCP, not necessarily just transfering one blob from one device to another.

Comment: For the other source you are providing: This doesn't answer my question. In the forum, you got this code from, the author knows for some reason, that he's awaiting 256 bytes of data and he wants to wait for reading until it fully arrived. I want to do the contrary: make sure it can never happen that data is left in the TCP queue (unintentionally).

Comment: Doing a little more searching on the subject, there are two examples of how to use the `QTCPSocket`, either in a blocking fashion or in a asynchronous way.  The asynchronous way, waits for a packet of some size, and then processes it, just like I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If a `QProgressDialog` shall be shown while receiving data from a socket it only works if any `QApplication::processEvents()` are sent (e.g. by the `QProgessDialog::setValue(int)` methode). This of course leads to the loss of `readyRead` signals as mentioned above.

So my workaround was a while loop including the processEvents command such as:

```
void slot_readSocketData() {
    while (m_pSocket->bytesAvailable()) {
        m_sReceived.append(m_pSocket->readAll());
        m_pProgessDialog->setValue(++m_iCnt);
    }//while
}//slot_readSocketData
```

If the slot is called once any additional `readyRead` signals can be ignored because the `bytesAvailable()` always returns the actual number after the `processEvents` call. Only on pausing of the stream the while loop ends. But then the next `readReady` is not missed and starts it again.

Comment: In this case, you should use a separate background worker thread for reading the incoming data. Processing GUI-related events within a non-GUI-related slot is usually a bad idea, although your example is probably simple enough to actually work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem right away with the readyRead slot. I disagree with the accepted answer; it doesn't solve the problem. Using bytesAvailable as Amartel described was the only reliable solution I found. Qt::QueuedConnection had no effect. In the following example, I'm deserializing a custom type, so it's easy to predict a minimum byte size. It never misses data.

```
void MyFunExample::readyRead()
{
    bool done = false;

    while (!done)
    {

        in_.startTransaction();

        DataLinkListStruct st;

        in_ >> st;

        if (!in_.commitTransaction())
            qDebug() << "Failed to commit transaction.";

        switch (st.type)
        {
        case  DataLinkXmitType::Matrix:

            for ( int i=0;i<st.numLists;++i)
            {
                for ( auto it=st.data[i].begin();it!=st.data[i].end();++it )
                {
                    qDebug() << (*it).toString();
                }
            }
            break;

        case DataLinkXmitType::SingleValue:

            qDebug() << st.value.toString();
            break;

        case DataLinkXmitType::Map:

            for (auto it=st.mapData.begin();it!=st.mapData.end();++it)
            {
                qDebug() << it.key() << " == " << it.value().toString();
            }
            break;
        }

        if ( client_->QIODevice::bytesAvailable() < sizeof(DataLinkListStruct) )
            done = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem, rather use signal readyRead() and socket.readall, i' m trying the following, just after connect without be sure :

```
    QByteArray RBuff;
if(m_socket->waitForConnected(3000))
{
    while (m_socket->ConnectedState == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState) {
        RBuff = m_socket->read(2048);
        SocketRead.append(RBuff);
        if (!SocketRead.isEmpty() && SocketRead.length() == 2048)
        {
            readData(SocketRead);
            SocketRead.remove(0,2048);
        }
        QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
    }

    //m_socket->close();*/
}
else
{
```